# Can minting be used to rug?

Tags: mining

So let's say:

1- Dev add 600$ to LP.
2- Users buy tokens, the lp is now worth 900$.
3- Dev mint 900$ worth of tokens.
4- Dev sells, the Lp is 0 now.

I am trying to learn solidity, but what's the flaw in that? Can it be used by idiots to scam people?

Answer (score 0):

yes what you said is completely correct and it already happened many times, be careful of those minting function as they are usually a big red flag in the contract

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed correct, but there is a small detail you missed.

If the owner mints new tokens and swap them for eth for example (basically sells them), it's technically not a rug pull.

He will also be unable to sell all his tokens for the same price as selling that much tokens will impact slippage due to extremely low liquidity, especially if the LP only has 900 bucks in it. You will never be able to remove all the tokens from the LP by just 'buying'  as the fraction of the last token is infinite.

The dude who bought 300 bucks of your token also overpaid due to low liquidity and slippage.